# Trying to identify a hash algorithm (an old one!)

Tags: algorithm, encryption, hash

I'm looking for generally what hash algorithm was used to create the following hash - all results are 24 bytes long and end in `'=='`.  The code probably originated over 15 years ago.  If I can get close I can probably work out additional details.  The resulting character set looks like ASCII a-Z plus a small set of additional characters such as `'+'` and `'/'`.  Not much else in thousands I can test.

**Example**:

```
pw = test1234

hash = msrZ8LbMS48yk9/yVsdcMQ==

hex = 6D73725A384C624D533438796B392F79567364634D513D3D
```

Comment: The output of a hash function is a sequence of bytes. To get a sequence of printable characters, these are often encoded with [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). It's obvious that Base64 was used here. But that doesn't help with identifying the hash function.

Comment: A Base64 string of 24 characters encodes 16 bytes = 128 bits. I would bet the hash function is MD5, but `base64(md5(utf8("test1234")))` is `"Ftek/KdELdo62TyacmWX5A=="` not `"msrZ8LbMS48yk9/yVsdcMQ=="`. So either it's a different hash function or it's a salted hash. Either way, it's extremely unlikely that anyone will be able to identify the algorithm unless you provide more information. Voting to close as unanswerable/off-topic.

Comment: Do you have an executable that runs the hash on any string you give it?

Comment: @dtb It's unlikely that this is a salted hash, since a salted hash has no 1 to 1 mapping between pw and hash.

Comment: It's not straightforward base 64 - there is no way to generate the first couple of characters (ms) using 7 bit ascii input (as in from a web form).  I can generate a hash from any text, but not in bulk.  I'm going to look for repeating patterns today to see if it is padded left or right & will post more later today.

Comment: Another note - it's either salted with EXACTLY the same value or not at all as I can change every field in the record and create the same password every time.  For what it's worth this is not a hack but an attempt to create a sort of single sign-on using credentials stored in an existing database that I don't have source code for YET.  Hopefully this will change in the future and I won't have this reverse engineering challenge...

Comment: As is implied in the above the == is padding.  See Wikipedia's [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) entry.